# What to use to SU to root from regular user for scp or sftp?

Tags: linux, su

I want to connect to a server but I need to turn root to be able to copy some files. I use WinSCP, I heard that it's possible to become root just after the authentification but for a sudoer without a password. The problem is that I need to write one to have the write permission..

Can someone make any suggestion for WinSCP or any other tool ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is badly worded, but there are a few things that I believe might work for you.

First: `su -`.  This should let you log in as root.
Second: `sudo -i`.  If you are in the `sudoers` file, this will enable you to become root.
Third: You can use `ssh root@machinename` to remotely log into a linux machine as root.
Fourth: `scp` is related to `ssh`, so when you use `scp` you could say something like `scp root@machine1:file root@machine2:file`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry for my english. The solution I found is to copy files to temp where I have write permission without su - then connect with putty to copy them to the right file

Answer (score 0):

Always is better work with ownership and permission than work with user root. For example, you can add your regular user to the root group and set SGID, read, write and execute on the folder where you will copy the files.